# How to use C++ CLI literal specifier?

Tags: c++-cli, clr

Here is my class. I'm getting errors on the line using the 'literal' modifier to declare the member type 'name'.

```
ref class CreditCardAccount 
{
public: 
    static CreditCardAccount ();
    CreditCardAccount (long number, double limit);
    void SetCreditCardLimit (double amount);
    bool MakePurchase (double amount);
    void MakeRepayment (double amount);
    void PrintStatement ();
    long GetAccountNumber ();
    static short GetNumOfAccounts ();   
    literal String name = "Super Platinum Card";
private:

    initonly long accountNumber;
    double currentBalance;
    double creditLimit;
    static short numOfAccounts;
    static double interestRate;
};
```

I'm getting errors when I try to reference the type 'name', for example:

```
Console::Write("Card name is ");
Console::WriteLine(CreditCardAccount::name);
```

Errors:

```
error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'String'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'name'
error C3845: 'CreditCardAccount::name': only static data members can be initialized inside a ref class or value type
```

Comment: Are you sure this isn't for C#?

Comment: Yes, i'm following a book, and doing most of it as written.

Comment: I don't know what book you're following, but there is definitely no `literal` keyword in C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx

Comment: It's C++: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5yzft952.aspx

Comment: Updated your tag and header ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had trouble with this too, the correct way to write should be:

```
literal System::String^ name = "Super Platinum Card";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.